# How to set the ignore_ssl_errors option for Capybara Webkit in spec_helper.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, capybara

In my spec_helper file I have:

```
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
```

capybara_webkit now has a `ignore_ssl_errors` option that I want to use. How do I specify that in my spec_helper?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to register the :webkit driver with the :ignore_ssl_errors option.

```
Capybara.register_driver :webkit do |app|
  Capybara::Driver::Webkit.new(app, :ignore_ssl_errors => true)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

As of writing (capybara-webkit 1.7.1), the configuration seems to have been simplified:

```
Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  config.ignore_ssl_errors
end
```

[(source)](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit#configuration)

Answer (score 2):

Somehow the above `register_driver` examples don't work with Capybara 1.1.4. The example below is taken from the [capybara `browser_spec.rb`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/blob/bca84f9a577963d99c99e735690905c5afb744b3/spec/browser_spec.rb#L11).

```
Capybara.register_driver :webkit_ignore_ssl do |app|
  browser = Capybara::Webkit::Browser.new(Capybara::Webkit::Connection.new).tap do |browser|
    browser.ignore_ssl_errors
  end
  Capybara::Webkit::Driver.new(app, :browser => browser)
end
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit_ignore_ssl
```

Answer (score 2):

As @hjblok says, the interface has changed in recent versions of capybara-webkit. You can simplify the solution slightly:

```
Capybara.register_driver :webkit_ignore_ssl do |app|
  Capybara::Webkit::Driver.new(app).tap {|d| d.browser.ignore_ssl_errors }
end
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit_ignore_ssl
```

Comment: `initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)

Answer (score 0):

When createing a new webkit Object you can use this to ignore the ssl errors

```
Capybara::Driver::Webkit.new({ :ignore_ssl_errors => true})
```

Comment: That gives me the error "Rack application timed out during boot"

Comment: `initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)