# Capybara Webkit raises InvalidResponseError "Unable to load URL"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm hitting an issue with Capybara Webkit where it raises the following exception when I try to run a feature spec.

```
Failure/Error: visit root_path
Capybara::Webkit::InvalidResponseError:
  Unable to load URL: http://test.unbound.com:4040/ because of error loading http://test.unbound.com:4040/: Unknown error
```

The failing spec looks like this:

```
it "should render a page", js: true do
  visit root_path
  current_path.should == root_path
end
```

This is the output when I use the `:webkit_debug` driver:

```
Run options: include {:line_numbers=>[72]}
Finished "EnableLogging" with response "Success()"
Wrote response true ""
Received "Visit"
Started "Visit"
Load started
"Visit" started page load
Started request to "http://test.unbound.com:4040/"
Finished "Visit" with response "Success()"
Received 0 from "http://test.unbound.com:4040/"
Page finished with false
Load finished
Page load from command finished
Wrote response false "{"class":"InvalidResponseError","message":"Unable to load URL: http://test.unbound.com:4040/ because of error loading http://test.unbound.com:4040/: Unknown error"}"
Received "Reset"
Started "Reset"
undefined|0|SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.
Finished "Reset" with response "Success()"
Wrote response true ""
```

The non-JS equivalent will pass with no exceptions raised. This version uses regular Capybara rather than Capybara webkit.

```
it "should render a page" do
  visit root_path
  current_path.should == root_path
end
```

It might be relevant that I'm forcing the host before each test like so:

```
# default_host_and_port will equal: "test.unbound.com:4040"
default_url_options[:host] = Rails.configuration.default_host_and_port
Capybara.app_host = "http://#{Rails.configuration.default_host_and_port}"
```

If I don't do that then I get issues running feature specs with regular Capybara.

Some things I've tried:

- Running the server in the test environment and visiting the `root_path` in the browser (as suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8896941/574190)). It loads fine. There will be a JS console error because `mixpanel` cannot be found but I think it is unlikely that is causing the problem.
- Using `Rack::ShowExceptions` to try to get a more detailed exception. Still get the same exception and backtrace.
- Running rspec with the `-b` flag. No difference.
- Adding `test.unbound.com` to my `/etc/hosts`. No difference.
- Telling Capybara to ignore SSL errors [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16064089/574190).

One clue:

- When I tail the test log, I never see a request to `GET /` come through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only fix is to remove host setting. That's the source of error and I see no reason you need that.

What if your tests running on a CI server or your peers' computer? They make changes to local test db but need to visit a remote server to see the changes?

Comment: You are correct that removing will fix the immediate issue. It introduces a problem where cookies are lost as requests redirect between SSL and non-SSL pages in the application. I guess that's a separate issue though.

Comment: David, yes, that really is another issue :)

Comment: hi Billy, i am having the same problem with cucumber when using @javascript

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting something like this in your global rspec before(:each) block? That fixed it for me.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    if Capybara.javascript_driver == :webkit
      # Allow loading of all external URLs
      page.driver.allow_url("*")
      # Ignore SSL errors
      page.driver.browser.ignore_ssl_errors
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: undefined method `allow_url' for #<Capybara::RackTest::Driver:0x00000006aa3240>